# Agregar columnas a archivo Excel con Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con un archivo Excel (xlsx) en conjunto con Pandas, lo que hago es leer el archivo y hacer operaciones con los datos, sin embargo quiero que se agregue una nueva columna en la cual este alojado los resultados de los datos.
Con esto leo los datos de cada columna:

```
fileEst = pd.read_excel('mate.xlsx')
datos = fileEst['intervalos']
for i in datos:
    ini,fin = i.split(',')
    ini = float(ini)
    fin = float(fin)
    xis = (ini+fin)//2
```

He intentado hacerlo algo como esto `fileEst['resultado']=xis`, sin embargo mi archivo no cambia y si intento esto se borran los datos anteriores.

```
for i in datos:
    ...
    fl = pd.DataFrame([[str(xis)]])
    fl.to_excel('mate.xlsx')
```

¿Cómo podría agregar una nueva columna en mi archivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu codigo es no puedes agregar la línea `fileEst['resultado']=xis` dentro del ciclo `for` e intentar cambiar la columna del `dataframe` en cada iteración. Los dataframes en pandas NO son mutables, por tanto, te estará dando error cada vez que lo intentes cambiar.

La solución es simple. Crea una lista donde guardes todos los valores de tus cálculos y la adjuntas en el archivo antes de guardar el dataframe. Basado en tu código sería algo como esto:

```
fileEst = pd.read_excel('mate.xlsx')
datos = fileEst['intervalos']
xis = []
for i in datos:
    ini,fin = i.split(',')
    ini = float(ini)
    fin = float(fin)
    xis.append((ini+fin)//2)
fileEst['resultado']=pd.DataFrame(xis)
fileEst.to_excel("mate.xlsx",index=False)
```

Pruebas:
Probé el código que te adjunto con los siguientes datos en un excel:
[image: Excel antes de Procesar]

Y obtuve:

[image: Excel después de procesar]

Comment: Una duda cuando edito el Excel la nueva columna se agrega más allá osea deja un columna vacía en la cual está el valor de unamed y cómo valores NaN, por que pasa eso?

Comment: @christian No puedo replicar lo que me dices. Yo ejecuto el script que te adjunto y no se me agrega ninguna columna vacía. Te adjunté mis resultados como una actualización de mi respuesta. Verifica que en tu Excel no tengas alguna otra columna nombrada. Los NaN que estás obteniendo dependen de tus datos y de las operaciones que estás realizando. Tampoco los obtuve. Considera adjuntar muestra de tus datos para la próxima.

Answer (score 1):

La función df.insert te puede ayudar, te adjunto un [link](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python-pandas/how-to-add-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas/#:%7E:text=df.-,insert()%20m%C3%A9todo%20para%20a%C3%B1adir%20una%20nueva%20columna%20en%20Pandas,columna%20en%20un%20%C3%ADndice%20espec%C3%ADfico.) donde puedes consultar un poco mas de información acerca de está función.

```
df.insert(6,"CALIF","")
```

El 6 pertenece al numero de columna nueva, el "CALIF" es el nombre, y por ultimo, lo que irá dentro de las columnas.

Comment: Gracias amigo por el link me sirvió